# Django ORM queryset substring on a column

Tags: django, django-orm

Consider below column in mysql table Employee.

```
emp_number
4-PQR-A111
3-MNO-333
2-DEF-222
1-ABC-111
```

I need to write django orm query for below mysql query which splits on emp_number column by '-' and matches against last index.

```
SELECT * from Employee WHERE substring_index(emp_number, '-', -1) = '111';
```

I cannot write endswith on a column like below:

```
Employee.objects.filter(emp_number__endswith='111').values('emp_number')
```

This will return below 2 records and I am expecting only one record.

```
4-PQR-A111
1-ABC-111
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about `Employee.objects.filter(emp_number__endswith='-111').values('emp_number')`?

OR

You can use `Employee.objects.filter(emp_number__endswith='-{}'.format(end_number)).values('emp_number')` where `end_number` is the value which you expect the employee number should end with.